# Filter GridView on TextBox's KeyPress event from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a TextBox with KeyPressed event and I want to filter GridView on that event using jquery/javascript.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" OnKeyPressed="txtSearch_KeyPressed()">
</asp:TextBox>

<script>
  function txtSearch_KeyPressed()
  {
      // gvBanquet is an ID of GridView and SearchBanquet method returns a DataTable
      gvBanquet.DataSource = DLBqt.SearchBanquet(txtSearch.Text.Trim());
      gvBanquet.DataBind();
  }
</script>
```

Note that GridView binding code is from **.CS** file:

```
gvBanquet.DataSource = DLBqt.SearchBanquet(txtSearch.Text.Trim());
gvBanquet.DataBind();
```

I don't know how it will work? It should bind on key pressing of TextBox.

---

**Edit:** I have find a solution server site `OnTextChanged` event of TextBox which bind the GridView after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of pressing a key.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged" 
    AutoPostBack="True" ></asp:TextBox>

protected void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvBanquet.DataSource = DLBqt.SearchBanquet(txtSearch.Text.Trim());
    gvBanquet.DataBind();
}
```

> I don't want it with OnTextChanged event but I think it would work on keypressed event using **JavaScript** or **jQuery** so I don't know how to do?

---

**Update:** I have tried below jQuery code to key pressed in textbox but its also not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#txtSearch').on("keyup", function () {
        // could bind bind GridView here??
        e.preventDefault();
    })
})
```

**Note:** GridView and TextBox both are inside UpdatePanel.

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>

  <div class="col-lg-4" style="padding-right:0px">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" Width="100%" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Search..." runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      <input id="inpHide" type="hidden" runat="server" />
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.col-lg-12 -->

  <div class="col-lg-12 table-responsive">
  <asp:GridView ID="gvBanquet" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" runat="server" 
      AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="gvBanquet_RowCommand" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" 
      EmptyDataText="No record found!" OnPageIndexChanging="gvBanquet_PageIndexChanging" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
      >
      <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Banquet Name">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<% #Eval("bqtID") %>'></asp:Label>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("bqtName") %>' ></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("bqtUserName") %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("bqtType") %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Capacity">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblCapacity" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("bqtCapacity") %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("bqtPassword") %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("bqtEmail") %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("bqtPhone") %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cell No.">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblContactNo" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("bqtContactNo") %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("bqtLocation") %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField>
              <HeaderTemplate>
                  <center>Events</center>
              </HeaderTemplate>
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Button ID="btnStatus" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm" CommandName="Status" Text='<%# Eval("bqtStatus") %>' />
                  <asp:Button ID="btnEdiit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-sm" CommandName="EditRow" Text="Edit" />
                  <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-sm" CommandName="DeleteRow" Text="DELETE" />
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5cb85c" BorderColor="#4CAE4C" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
      <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-ys" />
  </asp:GridView>
     <asp:Label ID="lblNoRecords" runat="server" Text="No Record Found!"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use AJAX UpdatePanel?

Comment: where should I have to use UpdatePanel and how? Is it work with textbox evry key pressed from keyboard?

Comment: @Asif.Ali you are missing id selector in your code. it should be this $('#txtSearch').on("keyup", function () { Note "#" along with txtSearch

Comment: I have tried with this but not working. I'll edit

Comment: This will get you started with UpdatePanel https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OnTextChanged` instead on `OnKeyPressed` and also set `AutoPostBack="True"`on textbox and you can do whatever you want in code behind file it work properly.

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtSearch_Changed()" 
    AutoPostBack="True"> </asp:TextBox>
```

**C# Code**

**On Text Changed**

```
public void txtSearch_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvBanquet.DataSource = DLBqt.SearchBanquet(txtSearch.Text.Trim());
    gvBanquet.DataBind();
}
```

**Edit**

**On EveryKeyPress**

**ASPX**

```
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"  
    AutoPostBack="True"> </asp:TextBox>
 <script>
    $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>").keypress(function () {
        console.log("Handler for .keypress() called.");
        __doPostBack(this.name, 'OnKeyPress');
    });
</script>
```

**C#**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    var ctrlName = Request.Params[Page.postEventSourceID];
    var args = Request.Params[Page.postEventArgumentID];

    if(ctrlName == txtSearch.UniqueID && args == "OnKeyPress"){
        MyTextBox_OnKeyPress(ctrlName, args);
    }
}

private void MyTextBox_OnKeyPress(string ctrlName, string args){
    //your code goes here
}
```

Comment: I have also tried that not working on every key pressing. As I have stated above that it only works when you press **Enter** after writing a set of characters. But my problem is bind on every key pressing to write a single character.

Comment: it's not working on key press it's working on Text Change when you change text it fires that changed method

Comment: But my question is to bind GridView on every key pressed from keyboard. The solution that you provide, I also have that solution before your answer but not avail then I consider to Start Bounty.

Comment: when I try your **Edit** in your answer but no success!

Comment: You can try Edit change when you press any key it'll post back using jquery Method i  have test this code it'll post-back correctly

Comment: your code worked add important jQuery library into the code. :)

Comment: Thanks you @Asif.Ali

Answer (score 6):

I hope this solution would help even though its a bit different than the actual method you used.
Do the following carefully and if any change is needed do not hesitate to comment.
You need first to use the jquery's CDN library as following in the  section:(just in case people did not use it yet)

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Create A Button inside the update panel (the same one containing the gridview) and make it invisible using css not from visible attribute used in asp.net like this:

```
 <asp:button ID="InvisButton" runat="server" style="display:none;" OnClick="InvisButton_Click" />
```

The Button is used to trigger server side code to be able to bind the gridview
(pagemethods or webmethods does not allow usage of instance members since it uses  shared functions.

Place the Textbox Outside the update panel and remove the autopostback=true(in case you are using it).

At the end of the body use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').bind('keyup', function () {
            alert($('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').val());
            $('#<%=InvisButton.ClientID%>').click();

        });
    });

</script>
```

the jquery code is used to bind the keyup event ( similiar to the key pressed but after it the key is clicked) to a certain function where you can do whatever code you want. However, $('#InvisButton').click() is used to trigger the server side code of the button with the said ID or its click event handler. which in my case i used simple code, in your case maybe you could use it like this:

```
protected void InvisButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// place your wanted code here
gvBanquet.DataSource = DLBqt.SearchBanquet(txtSearch.Text.Trim());
gvBanquet.DataBind();
}
```

### Note:

Sorry if any function mistakes occur, i tried to convert from vb.net to C# and changing IDs.

Comment: Mouse cursor lost focus and it does not work when remove one element from input box

Answer (score 3):

You can use a WebMethod Function to call your filter data
Like this

```
private static int PageSize = 5;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindDummyRow();
    }
}

private void BindDummyRow()
{
    DataTable dummy = new DataTable();
    dummy.Columns.Add("CustomerID");
    dummy.Columns.Add("ContactName");
    dummy.Columns.Add("City");
    dummy.Rows.Add();
    gvCustomers.DataSource = dummy;
    gvCustomers.DataBind();
}

[WebMethod]
public static string GetCustomers(string searchTerm, int pageIndex)
{
    string query = "[GetCustomers_Pager]";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchTerm", searchTerm);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageIndex", pageIndex);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageSize", PageSize);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecordCount", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    return GetData(cmd, pageIndex).GetXml();
}

private static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd, int pageIndex)
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds, "Customers");
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Pager");
                dt.Columns.Add("PageIndex");
                dt.Columns.Add("PageSize");
                dt.Columns.Add("RecordCount");
                dt.Rows.Add();
                dt.Rows[0]["PageIndex"] = pageIndex;
                dt.Rows[0]["PageSize"] = PageSize;
                dt.Rows[0]["RecordCount"] = cmd.Parameters["@RecordCount"].Value;
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                return ds;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call it from .aspx page

```
     function GetCustomers(pageIndex) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "CS.aspx/GetCustomers",
            data: '{searchTerm: "' + SearchTerm() + '", pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

For More Reference:
https://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/685/

Answer (score 2):

Text changed will be working only when you use `AutoPostBack = true`

`AutoPostBack = true` permits control to post back to the server. It is associated with an Event.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true"  OnTextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged" >
</asp:TextBox>

protected void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvBanquet.DataSource = DLBqt.SearchBanquet(txtSearch.Text.Trim());
    gvBanquet.DataBind();
}
```

**Edit:**

On EveryKeyPress

**ASPX**

```
 <asp:textbox id="MyTextBox" runat="server" 
onkeypress="__doPostBack(this.name,'OnKeyPress');" ></asp:textbox>
```

**C#**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    var ctrlName = Request.Params[Page.postEventSourceID];
    var args = Request.Params[Page.postEventArgumentID];

    if(args == "OnKeyPress"){
        gvBanquet.DataSource = DLBqt.SearchBanquet(txtSearch.Text.Trim());
         gvBanquet.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it works on `AutoPostBack = true` but it not working on every key pressed from keyboard. It will work pressing **Enter** from keyboard.

Comment: @Asif.Ali you want it to work for on every key press rather than only with Enter ?

Comment: yes exactly. I think it would be using **JavaScript** or **jQuery**.

Comment: @Asif.Ali , hafiz edit might be suitable for your need , it didnt helped you ?

Comment: @Asif.Ali can you edit your question with how you tried so that i can see if , it it doesn't wil give another solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155376/discussion-between-webruster-and-asif-ali).

Answer (score 2):

you are missing id selector, replace your sample code with this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#txtSearch').on("keyup", function () {
    // could bind bind GridView here??
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

})

Answer (score 2):

1. Replace: `OnKeyPressed="txtSearch_KeyPressed()"`
   With: `AutoPostBack="true"`
2. View aspx code in design mode (where you see your user interface.)
3. Double click the textbox.
4. Add these 2 lines for binding within the automatically created method:

   ```
   gvBanquet.DataSource = DLBqt.SearchBanquet(txtSearch.Text.Trim());
   gvBanquet.DataBind();
   ```

Basically, every time a character is inserted into the textbox, a PostBack will occur and the new method automatically created by visual studio will execute (which if you've pasted the code will bind the data).

*If you are binding to a database each time, your code will eat memory and be very slow (rather load using Angularjs).

Comment: honestly I don't know about angularjs :(

Comment: There are many videos online which could help you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWwFMpgLP4k does it from start to finish in less than 20 minutes (if you have data and a willingness to learn something new, but if you dont,stick to your already implemented method method.)

Comment: I'm not interesting in learning in as my final year project is inside webforms with 3-tier archi. BTW thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can not filter text box from jQuery, infect .ASPX control could not call .CS code from jQuery/Javascript. You can achieve it by adding UpdatePanel into your .ASPX code and then add tag `AutopostBack=True`.

Comment: Yes your point is right but my problem was, it should filter gridview using jQuery or Javascript which is now solved by the help of @JKOU 's answer. And now I have solved my problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387363/filter-gridview-on-textboxs-keypressed-from-code-behind/46488534#46488534)

Answer (score 1):

Used this `'#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>'` syntax for asp controls IDs in jQuery instead of `'#txtSearch'`.

- Add this script:

  ```
  <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').bind('keyup', function (e) {
              $('#<%=btnInvisible.ClientID%>').click();
          });
      });

  </script>
  ```
- And in **.Aspx** code:

  ```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" placeholder="Search..." runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>

          <asp:Button ID="btnInvisible" runat="server" style="display: none" 
              OnClick="btnInvisible_Click" />

          // Place GridView here

      </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
  ```
- And in code-behind:

  ```
  protected void btnInvisible_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     gvBanquet.DataSource = DLBqt.SearchBanquet(txtSearch.Text.Trim());
     gvBanquet.DataBind();
  }
  ```
- **Results are:**

  [image]

  [image]

Comment: I already provide you similar kind of solution and you are saying my textbox and gridview are in update panel here you have only gridview in update panel.

Comment: Yes that was my problem as I placed TextBox and GridView inside Update Panel but @JKOU solved my problem by placing TextBox outside UpdatePanel and GridView and Invisible button is inside Updatepanel and then works `.bind` in script but not works `.keypress`

Comment: It does not work when we clear input in search box and mouse cursor also lost focus in search box